# Inserting attribute value in Print Composer into label based on spatial relationship

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression

I have this print layout in **QGIS print composer/atlas** in which I only have one layer being shown: land parcels. I am interested in having a label that will show what is the attribute of another layer I have based on a spatial relationship like intersects.

This other layer is a layer of land uses. The idea is to have next to the map what are the allowed uses for that particular plot. The image below recreates what I need.

[image]

It seems there is no straight way to build this expression within the context of the QGIS Print Composer, but I think I am missing something. The closest I got an expression that feeds my label object is this expression:

```
if(intersects(@atlas_geometry, geometry(get_feature('land_use', "fid", "fid" > 0))),
  "use",
  'No restriction')
```

However this expression is always returning `No restriction` and this I am absolutely sure it cannot be. Therefore, this leads me to believe the `intersects` part is not being evaluated as I think it is. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using an agregate function. In this case the expression is:

```
aggregate(
 layer:= 'land_use',
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:= land_use,
 concatenator:=' ',
 filter:=intersects($geometry, @atlas_geometry)
 )
```

Two notes on this. (1) Most of the credit goes to Ujaval Gandhi thanks to [this blog entry](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/12/summary-aggregation-qgis/). (2) I find it a bit counter-intuive that a non aggregation problem is solved using an aggregate. Still curious to know if alternative solutions exist.